# Export as 32-bit with CMake & C++ won't work

Tags: c++, g++

I have been trying to make a program for Windows with C++ and Linux. I imported some libraries and wrote the code. Now this is the config for CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

set(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE Release)
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER gcc)
set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS -m32)
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER g++)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "-std=c++14 -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=release64 -m32") 
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_PROGRAM NEVER)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_LIBRARY ONLY)
set(CMAKE_FIND_ROOT_PATH_MODE_INCLUDE ONLY)

project(qpsm)

add_executable(
    a.exe
    main.cpp
)

add_executable(
    a.run
    main.cpp
)
```

I know it's not very efficent, but it does the job for Linux. When it compiles for Windows and I try to open it on a Windows Machine it gives me the error with the title **Not supported 16 Bit-Application** that a feature called `"\??\C:\Users\kroyz\Downloads\a.exe" cannot be run due to a incompatibility with 64-Bit Versions`.

I know I am very bad at trying to explain things and errors so let me know if I did something wrong

Regards,
Alex

Comment: Try removing `set(CMAKE_C_FLAGS -m32)` and `-m32` and let the compiler default to the native architecture.

Comment: @RichardCritten Same result, doesn't work :(

Comment: I've been able to create a CMake project with Visual Studio 2022 17.3.1 on a Windows 10 machine with that code you posted, and run both `a.exe.exe` and `a.run.exe` output executables. I did get two "unknown option" warnings, one for `-std=c++14`, which I fixed changing it to `/std:c++14`, and the other one for `-m32`.

Comment: @rturrado I tried `/std:c++14` but it gives me `c++: error: /std=c++14: linker input file not found` Any idea?

Comment: That `=` at `/std=c++14` is quite confusing. You're trying to compile in a Windows machine, aren't you? Just from a command line or from an IDE such as Visual Studio? I guess best thing you can do is to upload your project to Github and share it so that we can have a look. You can also build it from Github using Github actions.

Comment: @rturrado I am actually trying to compile on a Linux machine, I added that since theres no other option for me left when I was searching for this error on a Linux machine. Hope that helps!

Comment: If you were in Windows Visual Studio, you could cross-compile to Linux using a WSL target. I don't know if that's possible the other way around, i.e., cross-compiling from Linux to a Windows target. What I'd do in your case: have a look at CMakePresets.json [here](https://github.com/cpp-best-practices/cmake_conan_boilerplate_template). Try to replicate it with a Linux-gcc preset and a Windows-msvc preset. Then run your cmake and build your executables both in Linux and Windows.

Comment: @rturrado Sorry for the late reply, I am using VSCode instead of Visual Studio and I am not sure how to cross-compile in VSCode. Also the CMakePresets doesn't ring a bell for me. Also are you sure about the gcc, I thought it was only used for C applications and not C++?